# Parse-based app not differentiating between anonymous and normal user

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, segue

The current behavior of my app is:
Launch app
Enter a valid username and password (from login screen)
Click on Login
You are taken to the Main Menu which looks like:

[image]

I logout and then get taken back to the login screen which looks like this:
[image]

I then:
Click on Guest

The segue:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: (UIStoryboardSegue!), sender: AnyObject!) {

    if (segue.identifier == "go-to-main-menu") {
        var svc = segue!.destinationViewController as MainMenuViewController
        svc.toPass = self.signUpObjectId
        println("inside login prep for segue, objectId: ")
        println(svc.toPass)

    }
```

The if clause is a bit silly since we only have one segue at this point but and both buttons use the same segue identifier but that's not the issue or the cause, I believe.

I call(?) the segue in the following manner (from both the Guest and Login button of the Login view):

```
//Go to main menu
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("go-to-main-menu", sender: nil)
```

I've also tried it with sender: self with not much if any perceptible  difference.

It sends the app to the Main Menu except I have added coded in the viewDidLoad method that checks for type of user and then hides the Profile button and modifies the title of the Logout button if the user is a Parse anonymous user:

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //Hide my account button if user is guest and ensure title is LOGIN for but logout/login button if user is GUEST
    if PFAnonymousUtils.isLinkedWithUser(PFUser.currentUser()) {
        profileButton.hidden = false
        loginButton.setTitle("Logout", forState: .Normal)
    } else if PFUser.currentUser() != nil {
        profileButton.hidden = false
        loginButton.setTitle("Logout", forState: .Normal)
    }
    else {
        myAccountButton.hidden = true
        profileButton.setTitle("Login", forState: .Normal)
    }
```

If I reset contents and settings on the iOS simulator and I delete the app from my phone, I get the same behavior:  the inital login and logout tests using normal and anonymous users seem to work ok.  But after a few times, if that, it keeps presenting the same style main menu (normal or guest) and will not changes, regardless of whether I am logging in as an anonymous user or normal user.

I'm very confused as to how this would start working correctly than start failing.  My guess is that the user credentials are getting overwritten or lost somehow but I am new to Parse and not sure how to debug that kind of issue.  Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Or if I've been looking at this for too many hours and can't see the small, stupid mistake I am making.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parse.com caches the user object for you, so you should try examining PFUser.currentUser() at various points when you think the user is logged in or logged out to confirm that in fact the reality matches your expectations. Even just logging PFUser.currentUser().description() to the console throughout the process could help you.

Comment: I will give that a shot once I get access to my mac today (about 5 PM EST).  Thanks for the description tip.

Comment: This totally put me over the hump.  Thanks so much.